# Unable to access wamp server from outside my computer

Tags: wamp

I have installed wamp and set up the wampserver. Localhost seems to work. But when I enter my computers public ip(cmyip.com) from another machine it says webpage cannot be displayed. Port forwarding has been set and my port is open. (I have checked it with canyouseeme.org). Firewall exception have been handled. What else could be going wrong.

Comment: You might try looking-for/asking this on http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: Note that Serverfault is strictly for IT professionals only http://serverfault.com/faq.