# WAMP - World Wide Access

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I have installed WAMP on my computer running Windows 7. The Apache is running on port 80. I am searching here and there and everybody has its own solution. None of it fulfil the requirement.

Information:

```
Local IP: 192.168.15.52
External IP: 139.190.233.170 (Collected from whatsmyip.org)
```

Changed httpd.conf file:

```
ServerName 139.190.233.170:80

DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
     Order Deny,Allow
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have also added some rule for port 80 in Windows Firewall and also forward port for my LAN IP. Here is the pic:

[image: My Router Config]

Nothing happens after all that. Clicking "Put Online" and watching it to go green, nothing happens. I can access `www` directory by either localhost IP address (127.0.0.1) or my LAN IP address (192.168.15.152).

**Questions:**

Is it really possible to put WAMP for world wide access?
If it is possible, then how?

I have been searching around but none of them works. I have also searched SO:

[Unable to access wamp server from outside my computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462769/unable-to-access-wamp-server-from-outside-my-computer)

[How can i put my WAMP online for someone to access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003644/how-can-i-put-my-wamp-online-for-someone-to-access)

e.t.c

Some external sites:

http://www.computerforums.org/forums/server-administration/wamp-server-wont-work-outside-lan-help-207071.html

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091005091249AAQrHxR

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-accessing-wp-externally-using-wamp

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/self-hosted-wp-wamp-server-not-connecting-externally

http://webhosting.bigresource.com/WAMP-Access-Website-with-my-WAN-IP-pg1Bh4bJ.html

http://guides.jlbn.net/setaccess/setaccess1.html

Comment: It's possible yes. I know people using it in production. But that's using vhosts, but the principle should remain the same.

Comment: @LeonardChallis vhosts means Virtual Hosts? a VPS? I have also seen people running them for development as well as production but I don't know how to setup that for me. Someone suggested me to use Linux operating system e.g. Ubuntu. It is very easy to handle servers on it.

Comment: No, it's basically a way of handling multiple domains in apache. It just simplifies things for multiple sites. I have added that info to my answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, yes.

I would suggest momentarily disabling the firewalls, trying the connection and seeing if it works. If it does, you know it's firewall - turn windows one on and the other one by one to eliminate them. If it doesn't, you know you have issues.

Remember to run `httpd -t` from the command prompt to verify that your config is free of errors and of course make sure you restart apache and the W is green in the task bar. Make sure it actually is restarting, too - as some times things like mail servers (hMailServer I am particularly aware of) can stop it happening. In this case you need to restart the `wampapache` service from the services control panel (Start > `services.msc`).

Here's some extra info though, as you might be better setting up dynamic DNS. I use DynDNS and have the following vhosts conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.dyndns.org

  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/mysite/
  <Directory /home/mysite/>
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  # some logging stuff I cut out here

</VirtualHost>
```

Put that in `mysite.conf` inside `c:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/conf/virtual`. The `mysite.dyndns.org` is the host I have set up at dyndns. Finally, to make virtual hosts work, add  this to your `httpd.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Include "c:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/conf/virtual/*.conf"
```

Now, if it still doesn't work you you probably have other issues. Can you telnet on port 80 to that above address? See above firewall issues.

Comment: Let me see. I will get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Hey man! I have turned the firewall off but still Chrome shows `"This web page is not available"` when I access http://139.190.233.170/ from it. I have used `telnet 192.168.15.152 80` it shows blank black screen with blinking cursor. I have read somewhere that blank screen means connection succesful.

Comment: I have also used this Port Scanner service which tells that I have open port 80 with HTTP server running. http://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/server/

Comment: @Muhammad Talha Akbar what was the solution than?

Comment: @tomasz74 I got it running by forwarding the port 80 and adding exception in Windows Firewall. You also have to edit some settings and ask one of your friend to visit your external IP. You cannot visit by yourself. If you want to, use `localhost`. If you want to visit from another device connected to same network, use internal IP. My one is `192.168.15.*` :P